# SSIS can't use variables (Flat File > OLE DB Command), Must declare the scalar variable "@"

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, oledb

Apologies, I'm an SSIS noob and I'm struggling with trying to import a flat file and do an OLE DB command WHILE including a variable in the SqlCommand.

[image: Data Flow]

You can see my query and the attempt to include an already defined variable.  The error is displayed below:

[image: Advanced Editor for OLE DB Command]

Must declare the scalar variable "@"  I understand what the error is saying, but after hours of searching, I cannot figure out how to use variable in the OLE DB Command.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Some of the commands require you to use "?" in place of variables (call your parameters "0", "1", "2", etc.), and others the `@variable` syntax. Make sure you have variables mapped to your parameters as well.

Comment: Definitely tried that (using ? in place of the variable name).  The issue is I have to map that ? to an input column and none of my variables are visible from the input column drop down list.  Just the columns from the flat file source...

Comment: Looks like the Derived Column transformation might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: You are on the right track, use derived column to inject the variable into the dataflow. Also, if you care you will not get great performance from using the OLE DB command - it results in singleton updates for all the rows that it processes.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working!  What do you recommend in place of the OLE DB command?

Comment: You can use the "Execute SQL command" on the control flow after your dataflow and do an update over the entire dataset

Comment: The general approach is to write the updates into a staging table and then use a execute sql task after the dataflow to perform set based update. While I don't like using temp tables, this article was the first hit for the [pattern](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DanMatisis/ssas/689/ssis-updating-a-table-with-a-temp-table-not-an-ole-db-command)  Feel free to post your solution below, I'll upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the ssis variable [user::ClientID] into a derived column and add it to the data flow.  You should be able to use a ? and assign that value to your query just like any other value in your data flow.